# ssd won't mount: bad superblock but no bad blocks: write errors

Tags: disk, smartctl, e2fsck

*just noticed I was using SDD for SSD. Corrected*

I need help interpreting this situation. `/dev/sda` is a data disk backed up and with reproducible data so this is not system critical but I'd like to avoid the effort of restoring/reconstructing the data some of which will be quite time consuming

Is recovery / repair possible?

If so how?  If I wipe the disk for re-use what is its reliability?

Summary (detailed reports below):

- will not mount: bad superblock
- badblocks finds no bad blocks
- smartctl reports no errors
- fsck cannot set superblock flags
- fdisk shows clean partition
- dmesg shows write errors
- parted shows 792 GB free of 1 TB drive

Mount ssd fails as so:

```
 [stephen@meer ~]$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda
 mount: /mnt/sda: can't read superblock on /dev/sda1.
        dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
 [stephen@meer ~]$
```

but  badblocks finds no bad blocks

```
 [root@meer stephen]# badblocks -v /dev/sda1              
 Checking blocks 0 to 976760831
 Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
 Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

But smartctl finds no errors

```
 [root@meer stephen]# smartctl -a /dev/sda 
 smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-5.17.9-arch1-1] (local build)
 Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
 
 === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
 Model Family:     WD Blue / Red / Green SSDs
 Device Model:     WDC  WDS100T2B0A-00SM50
 Serial Number:    213159800516
 LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 8bc4fdc6e
 Firmware Version: 415020WD
 User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
 Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
 Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
 Form Factor:      2.5 inches
 TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
 Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
 ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
 SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
 Local Time is:    Tue May 24 16:06:23 2022 PDT
 SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
 SMART support is: Enabled
 
 === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
 SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
 
 General SMART Values:
 Offline data collection status:  (0x00)    Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
 Self-test execution status:      (   0)    The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
 Total time to complete Offline 
 data collection:       (    0) seconds.
 Offline data collection
 capabilities:           (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
 SMART capabilities:            (0x0003)    Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
 Error logging capability:        (0x01)    Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
 Short self-test routine 
 recommended polling time:   (   2) minutes.
 Extended self-test routine
 recommended polling time:   (  10) minutes.
 
 SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 4
 Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
 ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
   5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       124
   9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1470
  12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       134
 165 Block_Erase_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       4312400063
 166 Minimum_PE_Cycles_TLC   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
 167 Max_Bad_Blocks_per_Die  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       65
 168 Maximum_PE_Cycles_TLC   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       14
 169 Total_Bad_Blocks        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       630
 170 Grown_Bad_Blocks        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       124
 171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       128
 172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
 173 Average_PE_Cycles_TLC   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2
 174 Unexpected_Power_Loss   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       90
 184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
 187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
 188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       64
 194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   070   053   ---    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 18/53)
 199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
 230 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   001   001   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0x002600140026
 232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   097   097   004    Pre-fail  Always       -       97
 233 NAND_GB_Written_TLC     0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2703
 234 NAND_GB_Written_SLC     0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2842
 241 Host_Writes_GiB         0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       466
 242 Host_Reads_GiB          0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       622
 244 Temp_Throttle_Status    0x0032   000   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
 
 SMART Error Log Version: 1
 No Errors Logged
 
 SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
 Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
 # 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1470         -
 
 Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

and fsck fails as so:

```
 [root@meer ~]# e2fsck -cfpv /dev/sda1
 /dev/sda1: recovering journal
 e2fsck: Input/output error while recovering journal of /dev/sda1
 e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/sda1
 
 
 /dev/sda1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
 
 
 
 
 
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 121899008 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#31 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 07 44 08 00 00 00 08 00
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#31 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#31 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#31 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: error: { ABRT }
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: cmd ca/00:08:00:08:44/00:00:00:00:00/e7 tag 31 dma 4096 out
                                       res 51/04:08:00:08:44/00:00:07:00:00/e7 Emask 0x1 (device error)
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: failed command: WRITE DMA
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3: EH complete
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: error: { ABRT }
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: cmd ca/00:08:00:08:44/00:00:00:00:00/e7 tag 6 dma 4096 out
                                       res 51/04:08:00:08:44/00:00:07:00:00/e7 Emask 0x1 (device error)
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: failed command: WRITE DMA
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
 May 24 15:38:29 meer kernel: ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
```

Partitioning as seen by fdisk.

```
 Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
 Disk model: WDC  WDS100T2B0A
 Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 Disklabel type: gpt
 Disk identifier: 3F701164-2CF8-6D48-A94E-478634C140BE
 
 Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
 /dev/sda1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Linux filesystem
```

From dmesg

```
 [ 5292.895300] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
 [ 5292.895315] ata3: EH complete
 [ 5293.021851] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
 [ 5293.021859] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
 [ 5293.021864] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE DMA
 [ 5293.021866] ata3.00: cmd ca/00:08:00:08:44/00:00:00:00:00/e7 tag 18 dma 4096 out
                         res 51/04:08:00:08:44/00:00:07:00:00/e7 Emask 0x1 (device error)
 [ 5293.021874] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
 [ 5293.021877] ata3.00: error: { ABRT }
```

parted :

```
 root@meer stephen]# parted /dev/sda
 GNU Parted 3.5
 Using /dev/sda
 Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
 (parted) print free                                                       
 Model: ATA WDC WDS100T2B0A (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: gpt
 Disk Flags: 
 
 Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
         17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
  1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  ext4
         1000GB  1000GB  729kB   Free Space
```

Comment: @roaima Replaced smartctl section with full output. `smartctl -a` edit

Comment: What does the partition table look like, anything in `dmesg`?

Comment: @rfmodulator added

Comment: `ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33` 1995 has called, they want their IDE hard drives back! This has nothing to do with your drive failure (probably), but you should definitely configure your UEFI to *not* emulate an IDE interface for SATA or NVMe SSDs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I had no idea I'd done that. Where did I do it? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you've been doing with this disk, but that's crazy numbers! Looking at that output that SSD has been on:

- 1470 hours (61 days)
- performed 4312400063 (2.0GiB) block erases
- 163210068006 (76TiB) media writes.

That's a constant 16MiB a second of writes over 61 days.

I imagine you've got internal NAND failure. You might not be able to get your data back.

I suggest your best solution here going forwards is to use a raid mirror of some form to buffer the errors between multiple disks.

Ideally, it would be two disks of different ages and/or different production batches to attempt to spread out the distribution of errors and failures between multiple disks.

Just to clarify, I consider that an abnormally high amount of writes over a very short period. You're going to need to factor that in to the storage setup you go with.

Comment: It's a data drive for an always-on computer. It has one running VirtualBox VM and sometimes two. The VM is a torrent host that is nearly always receiving, always seeding. I keep my Dropbox on there to which I mirror my git. My Dropbox sits on three LAN hosts which contribute a small selection of logging... I suppose that would make it an active drive for a personal computer? Would that activity explain the numbers or is it likely I have some wacky process running away? Is the drive kaput? I understand SSDs have limited writes so... but smartctl seems okay.

Comment: Could this be the result of a general power failure?

Comment: It really seems as if the drive is worn out. Try to rescue the data with `testdisk`and then retire the drive

Comment: @gerhardd. Why does smartctl not detect that. Given the activity would a HDD be a better choice?

Comment: Well i guess it detected it. Have a look at the meaning of all the counter values. For constant high volume small-data writes, a HDD would obviously be the better solution.