# device to discard browser session writes

Tags: bash, shell-script, io

I use the Brave browser (a fork of Chromium) which writes session state to disk every second, activity that needlessly wears my SSD.

I am never interested in restoring my browser session.Never. So I have tried every possibly applicable setting but Brave insists. Something about usage stats I suspect.

I wonder if I could create a memory file. I tried a fifo but that locked up the browser.

Is there some other memory-based device. I see there is a RAM drive but I don't want to thwart all of the browser's writes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> activity that needlessly wears my SSD.

No, or at least not by any measurable amount; writing a few KB every second will literally take centuries to wear down your ssd.

And that is totally ignoring the fact that there is file system buffers.

So, ignore this, if it's just about the SSD.

You *will* have to let your browser write to disk regularly, anyways (and quite likely far more data), to retain it's full functionality.

Comment: Well that's good to hear.Thank you. I ask because I just had a SSD give up because of too many writes. It wasn't even a year old.So I'm looking at all activity that could explain why I had so many writes. See MatthewIfe's comment here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703733/ssd-wont-mount-bad-superblock-but-no-bad-blocks-write-errors/703778#703778

Comment: htop is a nice program that you can configure to show average I/O rates per running process. If this is really brave, then you should see several megabytes per second fly by all the time. My money would rather be on things like Spotify or steam or some buggy non-browser software

Comment: Oh wait you say one is a torrent box? That sounds like the culprit right there.

Answer (score 1):

[Profile-sync-daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/profile-sync-daemon)  was created exactly for this reason.

BTW, Chromium based web browser aren't even that bad in this regard, Firefox writes several times more data while working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to solve the problem by configuring the causing application and not the OS .

Suggesting to investigate this [article](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/sessionstorage/)